# JQGrid - OndblClickRow event to select field value by row selected

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm really struggling with this and can't seem to get this to work.

Basically I have a bookings table, e.g.

```
id    bookref    account    fare

1     BR1          101      10.00

2     BR2          202      20.00
```

My Jqgrid shows all this information, what I want to do is get the bookref value by which row is selected. The current function I have is:

```
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid)
    {
        var grid = $('#bookings');
        var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
        var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'bookref');

        alert(myCellData);

    },
```

When I double click the first row I get 'BR1' returned which is correct, if I double click any other row I still get 'BR1' when I should get 'BR2' if the second row is clicked.

Can somebody please help me with this? Would massively appreciated it

Comment: Why you use `sel_id` instead of the usage of `rowid` parameter instead? If you would have always the same value of `rowid` parameter you should verify whether you fill the grid with the data correctly. In the case you can include in your question more full definition of jqGrid (for example it could be interesting wether you use `multiselect: true`) and include the test data (at least two rows of data).

Comment: Well I was originally using the following code but I had the same problem,

Comment: ondblClickRow: function(rowid)
  {
  var rowData = new Array();
   rowData = $("#bookings").getRowData(rowid);

            $("#cp-bookings-dialog").dialog({ hide: 'slide', height: 625, width: 733, title: 'Booking Reference: - '+ rowData['bookref']});
  },

Comment: the grid is being displayed correctly, I can't see what the problem is?

Comment: I've just noticed that if I do a select all from tblbookings it works okay, but if I do select bookref, column2, column3.. this is when it stops working, any reason for this?

Comment: I can only repeat that you should edit your question and append it with the full definition of jqGrid and include the test data (at least two rows of data).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see here in my code, I am also using `ondblClickRow` in my grid.  If you see here, I am getting all row values and making my own changes what ever I want, and finally loading the job details page with `document.location.href`.
I am able to do this for all rows in the grid.

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowId) {
    var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(rowId); 
    var jobNumber = rowData['jobNumber'];
    var jobName = rowData['description'];
    var jobCustomer = rowData['customerName'];
    var jobStatus = rowData['jobStatus'];
    jobName = jobName.replace(/&/g, "``");
    jobName = jobName.replace(/#/, "__");
    var aQryStr = "jobNumber=" + jobNumber + "&jobName=" + jobName + "&jobCustomer=" + jobCustomer;
    console.log("./jobflow?token=view&" + aQryStr);
    document.location.href = "./jobflow?token=view&" + aQryStr;
},
```

If you want see my full grid code:

```
$("#jobsGrid").jqGrid({
        url:'../job_controller',
        datatype: 'JSON',
        mtype: 'POST',
        pager: jQuery('#jobsGridPager'),
        colNames:['Job #','Project','City', 'Rep', 'Status', 'Customer', 'Cust PO #', 'Rep. #'],
        colModel :[
            {name:'jobNumber', index:'jobNumber', align:'left', width:50, editable:true,hidden:false, edittype:'text',
                    editoptions:{size:30,readonly:true},editrules:{edithidden:false,required:false}},
            {name:'description', index:'description', align:'left', width:150,hidden:false, editable:true, 
                    editoptions:{size:20,readonly:false, alignText:'right'},editrules:{edithidden:true,required:true}},
            {name:'locationCity', index:'locationCity', align:'', width:90,hidden:false, editable:true,
                    editoptions:{size:20,readonly:false, alignText:'right'},editrules:{edithidden:true,required:true}},
            {name:'initials', index:'initials', align:'center', width:30,hidden:false, editable:true,
                    editoptions:{size:20,readonly:false, alignText:'right'},editrules:{edithidden:true,required:true}},
            {name:'jobStatus', index:'jobStatus', align:'center', width:60,hidden:false, editable:true,
                    editoptions:{size:20,readonly:false, alignText:'right'},editrules:{edithidden:true,required:true}},
            {name:'customerName', index:'customerName', align:'', width:150,hidden:false, editable:true, 
                    editoptions:{size:20,readonly:false, alignText:'right'},editrules:{edithidden:true,required:true}},
            {name:'customerPONumber', index:'customerPONumber', align:'center', width:90, hidden:false, editable:true, 
                    editoptions:{}, editrules:{edithidden:true,required:false}},
            {name:'code', index:'code', align:'center', width:40,hidden:false, editable:true,
                    editoptions:{size:20,readonly:false, alignText:'right'},editrules:{edithidden:true,required:true}}
        ],
        rowNum: 50, pgbuttons: true,    
        recordtext: '',
        rowList: [50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
        viewrecords: true,
        pager: '#jobsGridPager',
        sortname: 'employeeId', sortorder: "asc", imgpath: 'themes/basic/images',   caption: 'Jobs',
        height:547, width: 1140,/*scrollOffset:0,*/ rownumbers:true, altRows: true, altclass:'myAltRowClass', rownumWidth: 45,
        ondblClickRow: function(rowId) {
            var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(rowId); 
            var jobNumber = rowData['jobNumber'];
            var jobName = "" + rowData['description'];
            var jobCustomer = rowData['customerName'];
            var jobStatus = rowData['jobStatus'];
            jobName = jobName.replace(/&/g, "``");
            jobName = jobName.replace(/#/, "__");
            var aQryStr = "jobNumber=" + jobNumber + "&jobName=" + jobName + "&jobCustomer=" + jobCustomer;
            console.log("./jobflow?token=view&" + aQryStr);
            document.location.href = "./jobflow?token=view&" + aQryStr;
        },
        jsonReader : {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "id",
            userdata: "userdata"
        }
    }).navGrid('#jobsGridPager', add:false,edit:false,del:false,refresh:false,search:false}
    );
```

Comment: Than you, that what i was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

No use selrow, but this is no the row of the event, with concurrency can fail

Check this:

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid)
{   
    var grid = $('#bookings');    
    var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'bookref');
    alert(myCellData);
}
```